# Is a Web-Based SSH App Practical?

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to make a simple web app to do SSH commands. The UI would use ajax to handle the commands and return the response. I've been looking at the SSH2 functions of PHP to handle the SSH, but I can't figure out how to keep the connection open. I don't want to have to keep logging in for every new command, and it would be hard to keep track of what directory I was in. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Have you seen phpseclib library? See: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems to have the same problem.

Comment: What you are looking for cannot be implemented by a simple php script. This is against the nature of how a typical web request to a php script is processed. You do need some permanent instance running on the server, some kind of deamon which opens and holds the connection to the ssh server. Then you can connect to that deamon from a php script and fire a command. So you use that deamon as a kind of proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to its architecture PHP plugged into the web server can not have persistent handles to resources (such as files, sockets etc.). Consequently the answer is simple - you need some other server (not apache + PHP) to do the job. For example, IIS on Windows and Java servers let you have per-session storage and keep handles there.

Comment: Shouldn't this go as a comment, since it does not really offer a real answer?

Comment: Could it be handled with Python?

Comment: @James it's the problem of the server architecture, not of the language. Apache on linux creates a process per connection, which means that anything opened by the process is closed when the connection is closed (when the request is handled). The handle can't survive. So it's the architecture that matters, not the language. Arkascha's comment above applies - you need some persistent service running and keeping the connections.